# Creating Stored Procedure with TableName as parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am attempting to create a stored procedure where a table name is passed as a parameter, as well as updating contents of the table. Here is my code I have so far.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE TableSelect
    @TableName varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Declare @String varchar(100)
    SELECT @String = 'Update '
    SELECT @String = @String + @TableName
    SELECT @String = @String + 'Set Internet = 1'

    EXEC (@String)

END
GO
```

When I attempt to execute by this command:

```
EXEC TableSelect 'Waterford';
```

I get the error:

```
Msg 102, Lvevl 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Internet'.
```

Any help would be great. FYI, the column Internet, is just a bit so 0/1 or False/True. Thanks

Comment: I have done in the past where you can do this,
Declare String varchar(100)
SELECT String = 'SELECT * FROM '
SELECT String = String + TableName
EXEC (String)

Where the entered @TableName is displayed when executed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something seems really, really, really bad in this design.

1. Do you really have a large number of tables that have a column called `Internet`? What does that column even mean?
2. Do you really want to call this stored procedure such that it updates *every* row in the specified table? Why? You don't have a one-row table for every location / city / room, do you? Why?

Anyway, there are a couple of problems in your code; allow me to suggest a re-write, if you can't consider a complete redesign.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.TableSelect -- always use schema prefix!
    @TableName NVARCHAR(512) -- this must be a Unicode data type!
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- should at least validate that the @TableName is valid
    -- which can at least somewhat help avoid SQL injection
    IF OBJECT_ID(@TableName) IS NULL
    BEGIN
      RETURN;
    END

    DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(4000);-- should always use Unicode here too
        -- and always use semi-colons

    SET @String = N'Update ' + @TableName + N' Set Internet = 1';
        -- needed a space here ---------------^
        -- which PRINT @String would have shown you.

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @String;
        -- sp_executesql preferred over EXEC()
END
GO
```

Now, when you call it, specify the schema too, in both places, and specify the parameter name too, e.g.:

```
EXEC dbo.TableSelect @TableName = N'dbo.Waterford';
```

Relevant links:

- [Bad Habits to Kick : Avoiding the Schema Prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)
- Protecting yourself from SQL Injection - [Part 1](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/) / [Part 2](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/)
- [Ladies and gentlemen, start your semi-colons!](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)
- [Bad Habits to Kick : Using EXEC() instead of sp_executesql](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql)